# Can any one tell me what is wrong with my code,everytime i run it i get the io exception error

Tags: java, android, adb, uninstallation

> Here is my Code
> basically uses adb in the phone to un-install apps but its not working at the moment could any one help me out

```
       Process pro;
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        pro = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"pm uninstall –k ––user 0 
        com.google.android.gm"});
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(pro.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            output.append(line).append(" ");
            pro.waitFor();
        }
    } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String response = output.toString();
    System.out.println(response);
    Log.d("log", response);
```

> And here is the error i'm getting

```
     W/System.err: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "pm uninstall –k ––user 0 
    com.google.android.gm": error=13, Permission denied
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1050)
       W/System.err:     at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:698)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:563)
    at com.example.adb.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:23)
```

> Could any one solve this issue.

Comment: The arg in  Runtime.getRuntime().exec() is running on the adb shell of the device  which is being used . As far as i know.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue may be in the `new String[]{"pm uninstall –k ––user 0  com.google.android.gm"}`. Try using a normal string and not a string array.

Comment: i TRIED THAT TOO, BUT BY DOING SO I'M NOT GETTING ANY RESPONSE FROM THE CODE EVEN NO LOGS ARE SHOWING UP

Answer (score 0):

`Runtime.exec()` expects a `cmdarray` with the command name and arguments

```
pro = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"pm", "uninstall", "–k", "––user", "0", "com.google.android.gm"});
```